# Idiom/metaphor for an abrupt end of a dream

Tags: idiom-requests, metaphors

I am looking for an idiom or a metaphor that denotes an abrupt end to a dream. For example, one has a nightmare and they wake up abruptly, having a very unpleasant feeling from this sudden change in one's consciousness (from a state of dreaming to a state of wakefulness).

The closest metaphor I could think of is "abducted from the dream" or "abducted from dreaming" as in being pulled out suddenly and unpleasantly from the said dream. However, the word *"[abducted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abduct)"* does not seem to be the best option.

Comment: "He woke with a start" is a fairly common way to phrase it.

Comment: Cheers. However, it doesn't fit well enough with what I've described. See http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/start_2 at "wake with a start".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a dream (or nightmare) ends abruptly, I always feel that I was *[jolted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jolt)* from it.

> **jolt**, *tr.v.*: **3b**: to interfere with roughly, abruptly, and disconcertingly